# android activity onBackPressed not called

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        FragmentManager.BackStackEntry bSE = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1);
        Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(bSE.getName());
        if (frag instanceof BackButtonBlocker)
        {
            BackButtonBlocker callback = (BackButtonBlocker) frag;
            callback.onBackPressed();
        }
        else {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

BackButtonBlocker interface is for callback. my fragment implements BackButtonBlocker  but sometimes onBackPressed not occurs (onKeyUp as well).

when I open navigation drawer,  onBackPressed and full logic works exactly.

why should activity lose focus?

android.support.v4.app.Fragment

```
public interface BackButtonBlocker{ void onBackPressed();}
```

Comment: I have added fragment using ,,replace''.

Comment: I need to get callback in fragment, when back button is pressed. (e.g. for open any dialog..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding `setFocusableInTouchMode(true); requestFocus();` on Mainactivity's container view

Answer (score 0):

take out `super.onBackPressed();` from `else{}`

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is that, I have not implemented any interface to handle back pressed see below.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getDrawerLayout().isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        closeLeftMenu();
    }
else {

    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        finish(); // Means it is home and you can exit it from here.
    }
}}


When drawer is open just close it then use your code.
```

Comment: This is not problem here. I need to get callback in fragment, when back button is pressed. (e.g. for open any dialog..)

Comment: I have modified the condition this might help you.